# Can not find constraints created for UIView in constraints property

Tags: ios, swift, layout, nslayoutconstraint

According to docs the constraints instance property is

> The constraints held by the view.

```
var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] { get }
```

but when I created them with

```
  SampleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right ,constant: rightConstant).isActive = true
```

so it prints me a constraint

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4281540 UIButton:0x103d1d030'Next'.right == UIView:0x103d04740.right   (active)>
```

but constraints property shows me nothing. empty array [], but at the same time 
when i define constraints like heightAnchor and widthAnchor

```
   sampleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
   sampleview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true, and constraints array is not empty 

   [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c028bd10 UIButton:0x103d1c5e0'Skip'.height == 50   (active)>,
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c028bf40 UIButton:0x103d1c5e0'Skip'.width == 60   (active)>]
```

If someone knows , why so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Width and height constraints are added to the view itself , but constraints with otherViews are added to the other view if it's the parent if not to the shared parent between the two subviews , see this

[image]

so before you ask any view for it's constraints you should keep in mind the above photo

Answer (score 1):

The constraint will probably be in the constraints array of the UIView `right`. The `height` and `width` constraints are held by the view itself because they are constraints that only are in relation to the `SampleView` itself while the right anchor constraint is in relation to the UIView `right`.

The hierarchy is visually clearer when dealing with constraints in the Interface Builder.